# Test apk on wide rang of devices

Tags: android, apk

I developed an android app and now i want to test it.

How can I test it on a wide rang of different android's sdk versions and screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to test your application in multiple devices then you should use below platforms.

1. [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/)
2. [Monkop](https://www.monkop.com/)

Comment: Firebase Test Lab is safe than others in term of privacy.

Comment: I think both are safe for test.